# Jquery .val() browser differences

Tags: jquery, browser, input, wiki

**The Statement**
With jquery if you have a button element defined as follows: `<button value="123">456</button>`

Browsers will give you different values if you use either `.attr('value');` or `.val();`

---

**The reason?**
A `<button>` element is simply `<input type="button">` in a shorthand.

The way you would set the value of `<input type="button">` is to set `value="Click Me"`

Hence `<input type="button" value="Click Me">` is the same as `<button>Click Me</button>`.

---

**The Question**
Why does using `.val()` return different values on different browser. Who is correct?
*Firefox:* 
 .val() = 123 | displayed text = 456
*Chrome:* 
 .val() = 123 | displayed text = 456
>= Internet Explorer 8: 
 .val() = 123 | displayed text = 456
<= Internet Explorer 7: 
 .val() = 456 | displayed text = 456

Comment: http://www.jsfiddle.net/fD9xd/ - Both FF and IE are behaving identically for me... :-\

Comment: @Floyd Pink - IE 8 shows `123`, but IE 6 shows `456`.

Comment: I have corrected the post. <= IE 7 shows 456.

Comment: Ah! Add one more to the subtleties of how IE6 is uniquely evil and different...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading over the [w3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5) I'm led to believe that Chrome and Firefox are correct. Specifically because of this this snippet:

> Buttons created with the BUTTON
>   element function just like buttons
>   created with the INPUT element, but
>   they offer richer rendering
>   possibilities: **the BUTTON element may
>   have content.**

The W3 spec is referring to the information found between the `<button></button>` tags as **content** rather than **value**, which is what leads me to my observation. Another hint is that Internet Explorer is the only one returning a different value, and I'm fairly certain that Internet Explorer is the root of all anguish in the universe.

---

I also decided to test Safari 5, Opera, Chrome and Firefox 3.6.8 all on a Mac. All return 456 as text displayed and 123 as `.val()`

Comment: The problem seems to be that jQuery picks up the wrong value when it's IE 6.

Answer (score 0):

I am on IE 8.0.6001.* and it is behaving exactly like Firefox does - http://www.jsfiddle.net/AKGsd/3/

You've probably uncovered *yet* another bug/feature of Internet Exploiter older versions... Sigh !